# Unable to Compile Class for jsp I am not importing any class or package in my jsp

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am unable to understand why my spring boot is not rendering my jsp page. In my application.properties, I have

`spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/`

`spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp`

But still I am facing the following error as soon as I hit the URL:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [22] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [24] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [26] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Incorrect number of arguments for type HashSet<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>

An error occurred at line: [39] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [43] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [47] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:487) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:397) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1400) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_301]

[2m2021-09-30 15:56:54.770[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m13964[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9090-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [22] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [24] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [26] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Incorrect number of arguments for type HashSet<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>

An error occurred at line: [39] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [43] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [47] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

Stacktrace:] with root cause

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [22] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [24] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [26] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Incorrect number of arguments for type HashSet<E>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <>

An error occurred at line: [39] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [43] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

An error occurred at line: [47] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Geo Information\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.9090.279470005454375526\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\jsp\hello_jsp.java]
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:213) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:487) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:397) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1400) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar:9.0.53]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_301]
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. My jsp file is in `src->main->webapp->WEB-INF->jsp->home.jsp`. My controller is:

```
package com.example.JasperPractice.Controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class JasperController {
    
    @GetMapping("/get-employee")
    //@ResponseBody
    public String getEmployees() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

And my home.jsp page is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>This is home</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

According to me, there is some problem in my jsp because as soon as I hit the URL "get-employee" then my error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself... Actually the following dependency was causing error.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Removing it solved my problem